# Rails server says it cannot load the bcrypt gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

When I try to do this action I get the "LoadError (cannot load such file -- bcrypt)"

```
require 'bcrypt'

class PublicController < ApplicationController

  def attempt_login
        if params[:email].present? && params[:password].present?
            found_user = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first
            if found_user
                authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
            end
        end
        if authorized_user
            render(:text =>'authorized')
            redirect_to(:controller => 'private', :action => 'home')
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Invalid email or password"
            render :new
        end
  end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_password
end
```

I have tried all of the following in the gemfile and I get the same error every time:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~>3.1.11'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'
gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby
```

How can I get it to load the bcrypt gem?
I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: What does `bundle check` say?

Comment: "The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied"

Comment: How are you running your site? Where does that error show up?

Comment: When I try to load the one page that uses this controller, it brings up the error. The error that loads in the browser points to the line that says "require bcrypt" and if I take that line out, then it points to the line in my model that says "has_secure_password".  I will update my question with the code in the User model.

Comment: It could be the Ruby running your application is different from the Ruby running on the command-line.

Comment: Sorry- I'm new to ruby and rails.  Do you mean the version is different?

Comment: It's possible you have two different Ruby versions on your system, or the way the gems were installed is confusing to the way your server is running Ruby.

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: The first thing is to verify that's the case. I'm not sure how you installed your server, so you may want to re-check you've installed everything correctly. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com).

Comment: Everything worked fine until today, though.  So that makes me think that this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Remove `bcrypt` from your Gemfile.
2. Uninstall from your system by running `gem uninstall bcrypt`.
3. Add `gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'` to your Gemfile.
4. Run `bundle install`.
5. If you get errors, install Git https://git-scm.com/downloads and retry `bundle install`.

Source: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/102#issuecomment-284118731

Comment: Neither way worked.  Even with git installed it said "Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue."

Comment: Did it say more than that or only that?

Comment: I have no idea why this didn't work last week, but I just tried it again and it worked! Thank you so much!!!